# How to change text on the button?

Tags: patch-reversing, delphi

I am new to reversing and I need to get some reversing experience.
I need help on how to change the text on the Button.
for example my Delphi xe app have the button(Continue) and I want to change it to (Carry on).

How can I accomplish that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Open the executable file with a [hex editor](http://www.woodmann.com/collaborative/tools/index.php/Category:Hex_Editors), search for the string "`Continue`", and overwrite those bytes with the string "`Carry on`".