# Modyfying PE file data section

Tags: ollydbg, pe, strings

I am a bit new to RE, so forgive me any weird or stupid questions. 
The app that I am currently working on has strings I need to modify in .data section. That's why Ollydbg doesn't allow me to copy  changes to a new executable. I found out I can use resource editor to do that, but unfortunately I am able to change only menus and dialogs, icons and graphics. There are no strings including this one I want to change. To sum up, I'd like to know any method to change string located in data section.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [How to change text on the button?](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10785/how-to-change-text-on-the-button)

Comment: I had already searched for the string in hex editor. No results unfortunately. Any other ideas?

Comment: _"The app that I am currently working on has strings I need to modify in .data section."_ -- What tool are you currently using to see these strings?

Comment: I have already used Ollydbg, Resource Hacker, LordPE and a hex editor.

Comment: And in which tools have you successfully seen these strings?

Comment: I got them in ollydbg, but I am unable to save them changed(there is no such an option when I click right button on dump window). I found out that it happens when string is located in .data section. The string is loaded by LEA EAX, DWORD[register + xxx(don't remeber).

Comment: If you're only seeing the strings at runtime, then see http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/12441/1562

Comment: I suppose that's one of these:

Comment: the text may be hidden in the resource part of the executable

Comment: the text may be loaded from a resource file at runtime, possibly depending on the language of the windows installation

Comment: Oh my god, I finally found the solution. The program is calling dll which gets the string from ini file containing some technical stuff including my string. Jasson Geffner, thanks for your effort.